# How to access Session data from database

Tags: laravel

I want to access session data from database. Currently, I have changed default setting in session.php to database so that I can capture all the session columns in DB. But now I want to access these in my code. Do I need to create some session model or it's present out of the box just like user.php. Please help me.

Comment: You access the session data via Session class like Session::get('key');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should create `sessions` table [with these commands](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#introduction):

```
php artisan session:table
composer dump-autoload
php artisan migrate
```

Or you could manually create migration and run it, an example from documentation:

```
Schema::create('sessions', function ($table) {
    $table->string('id')->unique();
    $table->text('payload');
    $table->integer('last_activity');
});
```

After doing that, you can just use sessions as usual with `Session::` facade or `sessions()` helper:

```
session()->flash('message', 'Success!');
```

**Update**

If you need to access table data directly, you could do this:

DB::table('sessions')->get();

Or you could create SessionData() model and do this:

```
SessionData::all();
```

Comment: I already have created session table in my DB. But I am not able to understand how to access its data.

Comment: I can access User data by using user.php model ex: User::all() . But how to access session data. DO we have to create explicitly session model for it or we can simply access session::all()?

Comment: I am really sorry if I think I did not explain my question properly. What if I want to access all the entries present in my session table. Suppose I want to print all the rows present in my session table from my code. How to achieve it?

Comment: For user we can simply write code as User:all() to access all the contents since we had out of the box user.php model in built with the framework. but how to acheive this with session table?

Comment: You can use Query Builder: `DB::table('sessions')->all();`. I guess if you'll create `SessionData` model, you'll be able to access table data with Eloquent too, like `SessionData::all();`

Comment: I am getting this error (`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::all()`) when I am using `DB::table('sessions')->all(); `command.

Comment: Oh, try `get()` then. )

Comment: I am accepting your answer. Can you kindly update your original answer by putting the part where you replied as `DB::table('sessions')->all();` and  `SessionData::all();` as it will help others to see answer quickly.

Comment: Sure. I've added it to my answer.